# How to make Flutter GridView become paged when scrolling?

Tags: gridview, flutter

I'm making a slideable banner inside a Gridview By using

```
GridView.count(
    childAspectRatio: height / width,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    children: generateList(),
    crossAxisCount: 1,        
)
```

the child size will take the full width of the GridView. but now I need to make the scroll behavior become snapping per page like scrolling/swiping your phone at home screen.

is there any way to achieve such behavior?

Comment: what is `isPagingEnabled` exactly?

Comment: @pskink sorry if the example is confusing. I change the example I want to achieve on the question.

Comment: use `PageView` then - the docs say: *"A scrollable list that works page by page.

Each child of a page view is forced to be the same size as the viewport.

You can use a PageController to control which page is visible in the view. In addition to being able to control the pixel offset of the content inside the PageView, a PageController also lets you control the offset in terms of pages, which are increments of the viewport size."*

Comment: @pskink that makes sense. I will try it later. meanwhile, make your comment as an answer so I can select your answer if it solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @pskink state on the comment. `PageView` really do the job.

```
PageView(
   scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
   children: generateList(),
)
```

Too bad he didn't response my comment, so I decided to put his answer here so it can help anyone with the same problem